# Microsoft Access - SQL command to add a constraint

Tags: sql, ms-access

I Am new in stackoverflow and whats worst is I am new to Microsoft Access. My homework

Assume the Part table has been created, but there are no integrity constraints. Create the necessary integrity constraint to ensure that the only allowable values for the Class field are AP, HW, and SG. Ensure that the PartNum field is the primary key and that the PartNum field in the OrderLine table is a foreign key that must match the primary key of the Part table.

So I know how to create this by using Microsoft Access by going to the Validation Rule and add validation for AP, HW, and SG. However, I need to also create the query to show how this is done.

My code:

```
ALTER TABLE Parts
ADD CONSTRAINT classRule
CHECK IN Class(AP, HW, SG)
;
```

My textbook has an example which is similar to what I just wrote above. When I run this I get a Constraint error. What am I doing wrong? Also, the foreign key and primary key have already been made so I just need to write the sql query to display my result. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Either your textbook or lecturer is completely wrong. I reckon 50% of student questions on here fall in the same boat - the lecturer or textbook is simply incorrect or misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The `CHECK` clause exists but it's not a particularly good idea to use it because it can create [issues in you application](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/check-constraint-usage-t2762164.html).

That being said, your constraint should work but there are a couple things:

- You should avoid the use of the word `Class` as a field name. It's not a reserved word per se, but it's a VBA reserved word and while Access let you create that field, you may encounter strange problems elsewhere later.
- As Brian said, you need to use single quotes for string literals in your `CHECK`
- You can't create `CONTRAINT` with `CHECK` from the SQL Query Editor in Access, you'll get errors on the `CHECK` part every time you try.
  Instead you need to execute the DDL SQL from VBA: just open the VBA (Alt+F11) then type the following in the Immediate Window (Ctrl-G if you don't see it), then press ENTER:

  ```
  CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE Parts ADD CONSTRAINT ClassRule CHECK (Class IN ('AP', 'HW', 'SG'));"
  ```

If you don't get an error, then the constraint was properly executed, otherwise, double check that the syntax is correct, field names, parenthesis are properly balanced, and that the `Part` table is not open.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
ALTER TABLE Parts
ADD CONSTRAINT classRule
CHECK (class in ('AP', 'HW', 'SG'));
```

There is a space between CONSTRAINT and the name

Put conditions within the () after the CHECK keyword

Put literals within single quotes, as this is what differentiates field names from values

**Edit**

Although the above is valid syntax, from what I'm reading you may not be able to add a check constraint in Access via writing out the SQL, at least not in the SQL view of query designer.

You can add a check constraint by going to Design View for the table of interest, then on the row representing the column of interest, type the following on the line for "Validation Rule":

```
in ('AP', 'HW', 'SG')
```

http://www.databaseskill.com/1942875/

**"Note The check constraint statement can only be executed through the Jet OLE DB provider and ADO; it will return an error message if used though the Access SQL View user interface."**

Above quote is from the URL I just provided.

Comment: I tried your code and still no go! I am using MSAccess 2013, I don't know if that helps.

Comment: That is the proper syntax w/ most databases, ie. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba55e/1/0 however I just tried it in access 2013 as well and could not get it to work. It is odd because I can't find anything online that would suggest the access syntax is different. Although Access is a bizarre database... I'll let you know if I have any luck

Comment: @user3882733 just confirmed, in Access you cannot write out the sql for a check constraint in sql view http://www.databaseskill.com/1942875/ however if you were able to, the sql in my answer is what you would write.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Access implements quite a small subset of SQL, and adds many quirks to it (I like to call it "Bill's QL"). Indeed, field constraints (validation rules) must be defined in the table design view. Row constraints can also be defined in the table design view, opening the table properties window. As for referential integrity constraints, they can be defined in the "Relations" window (look for the "Relations" button somewhere in the ribbon... it's been a while since I've used access)

Comment: @Barranka Yes... it's a wonder why schools even use it for teaching sql considering it barely resembles any other widely used database, while all other widely used databases are similar in so many ways. It's practically a waste of time, especially considering no companies use it

Comment: @BrianDeMilia I agree with you. I used to be an Access fan some years ago, and I learned a lot about databases with it (including why Access is not a good RDBMS)... it's not such a bad learning tool, and it helps as an introduction to the database "ecosystem"... but then its limitations hit me in the face. It's advantages (VBA integration, easy-to-use UI, and of course it's power to connect to almost any other RDBMS through ODBC) are helpful, but its disadvantages will cause a lot of pain. By the way... yes, some companies use it (for small-scale tasks), at least around here ;)